# A* "Special Case"

Tags: algorithm

I'm implementing a 4-way A* algorithm according to this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNXfSOx4eEE

but mine is slightly different: to start, I have two maps and the targets are player units that can move from tile to tile, so I can not static my nodes and precompute their heuristics (at least I don't think I can according to what I've learned about this algorithm) I'm also doing a 4-way implement and wondering if I need a G value then or if the heuristic would suffice.

Now that you have an idea:
According to the video a "special case" has to be run on nodes found in the open list, but the check made no sense to me because I can't think of when the case would prove true, especially in my implement. The case is when a node is on the open list, you have to check where node A is the node you are on and Node B is the one on the list, then you check if A's G cost + movement is less than B's G cost, and if it is, you reparent B to be A's child. For reference, this explanation begins at 7:20.

In what scenario would this case occur? If I'm using a 4-way Taxicab Geometric implementation, then should I still calculate a movement cost? I'm pretty sure my f value would be dependent on my h value in this case.

I forgot to also ask, but in event of optimization, can I take nodes off the open list after I determine which node to move to?

Comment: You know, whoever keeps down voting all my questions and got me temporarily banned from asking them should realize that they don't need a code every damn time to answer a conceptual/technical question, and that they should know how to explain general concepts without a reference or sample data...

Comment: I guess the downvote is not caused due to lack of code. There are other problems with your question, such as the following: Don't expect anyone to watch a 14' video just to understand your question. Try to summarize the elementary content (preferably in a less wordy way) You haven't stated any relevant information on your scenario. How can the units move? Are they restricted to tile centers? Why does their movement make the heuristic not pre-calculable? What two maps do you refer to? Where is your start? Do you have any obstacles or otherwise differing movement costs?

Comment: I do summarize it, and the specific question I asked is mentioned to be at a specific time in a video, so getting acquainted with what I am talking about would take about a couple seconds.

Comment: I see at least three questions which are more or less related to each other. Additionally, I don't see how any of those questions refer to your "slight difference". Just to get clarity about symbols: `g` is the cost the a node so far, `h` is the expected cost from a node to the target and `f = g + h`, right?

Comment: I have obstacles, I do not calculate the heuristics for nodes that contain tiles that are impassable. The units move along an underlying 2D array that represents the cells of the map. it is irrelevant to my pathfinding algorithm, but I do state that this is a 4-way Taxicab implementation. I guess they are restricted to tile centers as the map is laid out over a 2D array and grid. My understanding is heuristic is the distance from a node to the target node. Using that, my heuristics would have to update each time a new target is found or a target moves, which I mentioned that the targets move.

Comment: The two maps I refer to are GameMap objects that contain their own grid for the sake of the AI's pathfinding. the movement costs are all the same, I used 10 for adjacent and again it's only 4-way, so there is no consideration for diagonal movement. Lastly, I don't see how mentioning my start point is relevant. The algorithm has to be dynamic as start and end points will be update each time a unit takes a turn.

Comment: And yes, that's correct. That's what I know about the algorithm.
h is heuristic, g is movement cost, and f is the sum of the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear from the beginning: A* is an algorithm that finds the shortest path from a fixed start to a fixed target in a static environment. I will go over a few alternatives for dynamic problems at the end of this answer.

The check you're curious about happens when you reach a node that has been visited before. The necessity of this check depends on your heuristic. Let's assume that the heuristic is the Manhattan distance to the target and the movement cost between nodes is constantly 1.

Let `B` be a node in the open list whose neighbor you've visited before, `A` the currently processed node, which is a neighbor of `B`, and `C` the current parent of `B`. Then, consider the following scenario, where the grey cells are walkable:

[image: Scenario]

You started at `S` and then propagated your way down to `C` with `g(C)=4, h(C)=2`. You find that you hit a wall and try another path which eventually comes to `A` with `g(A)=2, h(A)=4`. Now you analyze `B` which is already in the open list. Of course, the path from `S` to `B` is shorter through `A` than through `C`. So you need to update.

If you choose a node to visit from the open list, you remove this node from the open list and add it to the closed list.

Dynamic targets are not easy to follow. One option is to use A* to get a path from `S` to `T` and when you reach `T`, calculate a new path to the new location. You can also update the path while moving (e.g. calculate a new path every second).

There also exist dynamic path finding algorithms. Most perform multiple A* iterations and reuse the structures from previous iterations. Check [this paper](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/aamas10a.pdf) for some references (especially chapter 3). Fringe-Retrieving A* looks like a viable candidate.